# っちゅう after a verb

Tags: meaning, colloquial-language, dialects, contractions

To be clear, I am **not** asking about なか after a verb (which can mean "during"/"while"). While reading, I encountered:

> うちらに確実に勝てるっちゅうんか！！

Presumed meaning:

> You think you can definitely beat us!?

The speaker here generally speaks with a (stereotypical, borrowing from both 広島弁 and 大阪弁) western Japan accent (ie: だ->じゃ, だから -> じゃけえ, れば ->りゃあ, etc), so it's possible that this is something dialectical, but I can't find anything on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

っちゅう is a rather common colloquial contraction of っていう = という, so you may simply read it as

> うちらに確実に勝てるっていうのか！！

Comment: Thanks! I guess I should have been searching for っちゅう rather than ちゅう, since that simmplifies it. I updated the title to reflect the "proper" question so it can up in other's searches.